# If I have a background that requires killing someone who can't be killed in a similar story, can I kill them?

Tags: dnd-5e

I made a gnome monk that, as I thought would be good for his background, beat the mayor of Phandalin at a game of cards by cheating, and now the mayor is on his back. He wants to get the mayor off his back by any means neccessary. I have *The Dragon of Icespire Peak* campaign, in which the same mayor is locked behind a door. Now, I want to use this gnome in *The Lost Mine of Phandelver*, in which my DM has warned me we're about to come upon a situation that he's playtested multiple times, and every time some character has died. I want to die so I can come back as the gnome. This may be a bit of a problem(I see the 'my guy syndrome') for all of my friendly PCs. I have not told my DM about this yet, but plan to. Is this gnome someone I could play after my first character dies, where he's going to probably kill the mayor, or do I need to change his background?

Just note: ***PLEASE DON'T SPOIL THE*** *LOST MINE* ***CAMPAIGN TO ME.***

Comment: Voting to close as bad-subjective.  This is purely something to be worked out with the GM, not on RPG.stack

Answer (score 9):

### You are not asking yourself the correct question

The question you should ask yourself isn't "should I kill this NPC?", but "do I really want to play another character?".

You are talking about a gnome character you want to reroll into, but what about your current character? Assuming you have fun playing it, why would you want them to die? That is rather the opposite of a "My Guy" issue: "Your Guy" here isn't the gnome, it is the one you are trying to get killed, and this guy certainly doesn't want to die.

If you really don't like playing them, you should rather talk about it, with your DM at least and possibly also with your fellow players. Maybe they grew attached to this character, and although ultimately you should have the right to stop consenting to play this character you have to acknowledge they could possibly not enjoy putting efforts into interacting with a PC whose player doesn't actually take seriously.

Secondly, it seems that your DM here is warning you about a fight being very hard, not about some kind of dilemma where you have to pick one PC to die. Usually in those fight playing to die doesn't mean your fellow PC are going to be safe, it means you increase their chance to die too. It reads like a very good way to make yourself hated by your fellow players.

Once you have cleared all that, and only then, you can start asking your DM if your reroll concept is ok and agree with them about how to make the previous one go out with a bang.

Answer (score 7):

#### Ask your DM.

The DM is in charge of all world-building elements, so you need to work with them to fit your character background into the narrative of the world.